# How to handle views.py after joining two models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Here I've two models first one is **Contact** and second model is **Sent_replies**. So, what should I do in **views.py** so that If anyone send response in **Contact**, the data will also update in the **Sent_replies** model

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    message_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Sent_replies(models.Model):
    message_sender = models.ForeignKey(Contact,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message.name
```

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        phone = request.POST.get("phone")
        comment = request.POST.get("comment")
        if name != "":
            contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, comment=comment, date=datetime.today())
            contact.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your response has been submitted successfully!!!')
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Comment: What exactly is the function of `Sent_replies`? I do not see any added value of making a model that only refers to a `Contact`.

Comment: **Sent_replies** has two other variables, one is  **sent_email_subject** and another **sent_email_body**, However, I didn't mentioned them here @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are way of doing this, logic in your view only or create a signal to handle it.

logic in your views.py:

```
if name != "":
     contact = Contact.objects.create(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, comment=comment, date=datetime.today())
     Sent_replies.objects.create(message_sender=contact)
```

Using [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save) in your models.py file

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact)
def add_reply(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == True:
       Sent_replies.objects.create(message_sender=instance)
```

Comment: Hi, now if I want to find a data from **Sent_replies** model  base on that **message_id**,  can I write `Sent_replies_message_id = Sent_replies.objects.get(pk=message_id)`

Comment: @Sunjaree you would query like this `Sent_replies_message_id = Sent_replies.objects.get(message_sender__message_id=11)`

Comment: Thanks a lot btw is there any resources so that I can be more familiar with these syntax? For example I tried this way and was getting error `Sent_replies_message_id = Sent_replies.objects.get(message_sender.message_id=11)`

Comment: @Sunjaree the starting tutorial of django should cover the case you are asking, for more informations you can take a look at this section of the django query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/